# How to print python list object?

Tags: python-2.7, list

I have a list like bellow

```
{'list1':[a,b,c]}{'list2':[d,e,f]}
```

I want to print it like

```
list 1
a
b
c

list 2
d
e
f
```

How to do it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not a list.

Comment: You have a dictionary not a list, simply loop over the keys and values: `for k,v in yourvar.items(): print ('{}'.format(k));print('{}'.format('\n'.join(map(str, v))))`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: It's not even a dict. It looks sort of like two dicts, but really, it's so messed up and ambiguous that we'd need to see a lot more context to figure out the right way to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is not a list. They look like two dictionaries. You may use this code to get the required output.

```
dict1={'list1':["a","b","c"]}
dict2={'list2':["d","e","f"]}

import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(dict1)
df1=pd.DataFrame(dict2)
df
df1
```